# Defining one writable for whole Mapper/Reducer

Tags: hadoop

I read somewhere that there could be performance gain if we define output writables when Mapper/Reducer is created and that in Mapper/Reducer we should only set the value of that writable instead of creating the writable for each output record.

For example (in pseudo-code):

```
IntWritable idWritable = new IntWritable();

map(){
     idWritable.setValue(outputValue);
     emit(idWritable);
}
```

Is more optimal than:

```
map(){
     IntWritable idWritable = new IntWritable(outputValue);
     emit(idWritable);
}
```

Is this true? Is it really a good practice to define output writables when creating a Mapper/Reducer, which will be used for all output records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is true. In your second example you're creating a brand new `IntWritable` every time you process a record. This requires overhead for new memory allocation, and also means that the old `IntWritable` has to be garbage collected at some point. If you're processing millions of records and using a complex `Writable` (say with several `ints` and `Strings`), the heap can be filled very quickly.

Alternately, by just re-setting the value within the same object, no new memory needs to be allocated and no garbage collection needs to take place. It's much faster, but I can recommend doing your own experiments to confirm this.